# Sorting parallel arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a couple of parallel arrays called names and sales.  I have the user enter up to 100 salespeople (names, obviously) and their sales.  I have no problem printing these to a table.  The catch (for me, anyway) is that they need to be sorted in descending order according to sales.  I have made a function called `sort` which is coded (poorly - as I am just beginning to learn JavaScript) as:

```
function sort(names, sales) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var temp = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sales.length - 1; i++) {
        var min = i;
        for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        if (sales[j] < (sales[min])) min = j;
        temp = sales[i];
        sales[i] = sales[min];
        sales[min] = temp;
        temp = names[i];
        names[i] = names[min];
        names[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

I am in need of some help here, obviously.  Can anyone lend a hand to point out the (no doubt numerous) errors?

We have been instructed to write our own sort.  Sales and names are input through two different functions (`getName()` and `getSales()`) using prompts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why not use a single two-dimensional array, say, SalesArray, for example:

[ ['someName', 'someSale'],
  ['someName2', 'someSale2'],
]

Next, simply inspect SalesArray[i][1] while sorting.

As for sorting, try implementing [bubblesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), especially if you're new to sorting algorithms.

Comment: Of course, I should add that bubsort is a "bad" sorting algo.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just store both the name and sales in a single object? Then everything is in one array.

```
// Declare array
var people = new Array();

// Somewhere in a loop to add people...
var person = {
    name: "jdmichal",
    sales: 1000
};
people.push(person);

// Now sort based on the sales property in each object.
```

Comment: Darn, questions I never thought to address in the original post.  In the assignment, we are told to either use parallel arrays, or a 2 dimensional array.  I have never used a 2D array, and am just beginning to learn about parallel arrays, so I chose parallel.

Comment: Nor have we been taught 'push()'.  Looks like it would certainly do the trick, though.

Comment: @unit *Sigh.* And this is why programming assignments are terrible.