# Javascript sort an object with parallel arrays

Tags: javascript

If I have an object with parallel arrays:

```
var obj = {};
obj['aa'] = [5,2,7,0];
obj['bb'] = ['b', 'e', 'f', 'a'];
obj['cc'] = [12, 66, 77, 43];
```

How do I sort the arrays based on one of the values? For example, I want the three arrays sorted based on the value of the 'aa' array. I tried

```
obj.sort(function(a, b) {return aa.a - bb.a;});
```

But that doesn't work. It's obviously wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You could use multi-dimensional arrays instead. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320533/sorting-parallel-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to do a parallel sort based on the sorting of one of the Arrays, you can create an Array of Objects that hold the corresponding property of each object for the current index. Then just sort that like a normal Array of Objects and convert the result back.

```
obj.aa.map(function(_, i) {
    var o = {};
    for (var p in obj) {
        o[p] = obj[p][i];
    }
    return o
}).sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.aa - b.aa;

}).forEach(function(o, i) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        obj[p][i] = o[p];
    }
});
```

---

*As noted in the comment below, this could possibly fail because of certain optimizations.*

<s>If you're looking to do a parallel sort based on the sorting of one of the Arrays, you can create a sort helper that sorts the main Array, and caches the results, then plays back the results in sorts on the rest of the Arrays.</s>

```
function parallel_sort(fn, arr1 /*, arr2, ..., arrn */) {
    var results = [],
        playback = function() {
            var j = 0;
            return function() {
                return results[j++];
            };
        },
        i = 0;

    arr1.sort(function(a, b) {
        return results[i++] = fn(a, b);
    });

    for (var k = 2; k < arguments.length; k++) {
        arguments[k].sort(playback());
    }
}
```

---

So the concept is pretty simple overall. Just sort the first Array, but pass a function that wraps the actual sort function.

As the wrapper function is being invoked by the `.sort()` algorithm, it logs the result of the actual sorting function to an Array.

Then all we need to do is simply create another function that is passed as the sorting function for the secondary Arrays. This function does nothing but read back the results of the original sort, causing an identical ordering to take place.

---

You'd use it like this in your code...

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/jWg3n/

```
var obj = {};
obj['aa'] = [5,2,7,0];
obj['bb'] = ['b', 'e', 'f', 'a'];
obj['cc'] = [12, 66, 77, 43];

parallel_sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; },
              obj.aa,
              obj.bb,
              obj.cc
              );
```

---

And the result looks like this...

```
{
    "aa": [
        0,
        2,
        5,
        7
    ],
    "bb": [
        "a",
        "e",
        "b",
        "f"
    ],
    "cc": [
        43,
        66,
        12,
        77
    ]
}
```

The `obj.aa` was the primary sort, so `obj.bb` and `obj.cc` follow the ordering of `obj.aa`.

Comment: Isn't quicksort randomized?
Can one be sure that for other arrays their items will be compared in exactly the same order as the were for the first array?

Comment: @dr.scre: Good point. There can be optimizations that would not guarantee the same sort. It will only work if the sorting algorithm is consistently applied. I updated with a better solution.

Comment: Note that the code here won't work on non-numeric nor lone arrays. For a more general-purpose function, I'd recommend handling these common exceptions, by adding something like this: `var fn = function( a, b ){ return ( typeof a == 'number' && typeof b == 'number' ) ? ( a - b ) : ( a.toString() > b.toString() ); };` and `if( arguments.length < foo ){ arr1.sort( fn ); return; }`. Just a heads-up since it can otherwise fail silently and lead to confusion, since the code works on arrays in-place.

Comment: @dr.scre @user1106925 Regarding possible failure cases of the `parallel_sort` function and similar, have they been documented anywhere? It seems to continue to work fine in 2021, even in light of the many optimizations to the JS engines of modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort 'objects'. With the example above it cannot be sorted. Unless you want to sort each array within the object, which would be done as such

```
// loop through each item in your dataset
for (var i in data) {
    // make sure the item is actually part of dataset and not in herited
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // sort:
        data[i].sort(function(a,b) {
            return a-b;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the arrays have to be sorted in parallel based on one array. Your code sorts the arrays independently...

Comment: Ah, I see now. that's quite a bit more difficult

Comment: You can absolutely sort objects, you just have to choose a property or value to sort on.